# How to parameterize Git URL in Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline?

Tags: git, jenkins, multibranch-pipeline

Given is a list of repository URLS, which differ in only one part:

```
http://hostname/{A}.git
http://hostname/{B}.git
http://hostname/{C}.git
```

I want my multibranch pipeline to be able to checkout from a git-repository of my wish. And I want to be able to choose the repository each time I start the job with "Build with parameters".

So, I did some parameterization in my Jenkinsfile, like this:

```
properties(
[
parameters([
choice(name:'repository', choices'A\nB\nC')
]
)
]
)
```

The question: how do I add the choice variable (`'repository'`) into the configuration of my Jenkins multibranch build job? In Jenkins GUI under "/configure" I can see "Branch Sources", with the "Git" block, where I can put git-repo URL as "Project Repository". But how can I include the choice into git URL?

Answer (score 0):

I have some setup in my jenkins pipeline job.
Please check if this approach is going to help you.
################
In my jenkins pipeline groovy job, I defined there parameters.

```
def gitrepo1= "repo 1 url"    
def gitrepo2= "repo 2 url"
def gitrepo3= "repo 3 url"

then in pipelinejob function,
pipelinejob('jobname')

parameters 
{
choiceparam('gitrepo',[gitrepo1,gitrepo2,gitrepo3], '')
...............................
...............................
}
definiton 
{
......
}
```

Now when building job, If I select build with parameters, I can choose the value of the gitrepo from 3 options.

Thanks,
Subhadeep